# what are things that make bad output of HTML?

Tags: asp.net

I know that in ASP.NET web forms developers can't control the output HTML. But does this happen with every thing in ASP.NET web forms? or is there secific controls that we can't control the HTML of them?

Cheers.

Comment: I really do not understand what you mean "control the output html". I use web forms and I control everything I need, the html is what I render...

Comment: To get startet you could have a look at [this similar question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461901/asp-net-control-to-html-tag-equivalent/462013#462013). But it might depend also on the browser the client is using(BrowserCaps).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest rule of thumb is: the more the server control does for you, the more output markup there is going to be which you don't have control over.

The simplest is surely an `asp:Literal` - there's nothing in that beyond your control. An `asp:Label` is just a `<span>`. But once you work your way up to controls like `asp:GridView`, now you're talking some serious quantities of HTML and JavaScript being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the server controls will generate their own output. These would include anything that has the `runat = "server"` attribute. You have some control over the output, but it's *declarative* rather than *imperative*. Meaning you can tell the control what you'd like it to do, but not how to go about doing it.