# How to add ASP.NET control for <i></i> tags in Html and assign them inside .FindControl() method on .cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Does anyone knows How to add ASP.NET control for `<i></i>` tags?
i am looking for ASP.NET Control that is equivalent with `<i>` Html tag

in my case, I also want to implement .FindControl() method for it inside the *.cs* file.
Here's the part of the code..

Example.axcs

```
<asp:Panel id="forDiv" CssClass="input-group colorpicker-component" runat="server">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeree" class="form-control" runat="server" Style="width: auto"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Panel CssClass="input-group-append" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label CssClass="input-group-addon input-group-text" runat="server"><i></i></asp:Label>
                        </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

from the code above,
the FindControl method that I have implemented goes like this,

Example.ascx.cs

```
TextBox txtVal = e.Row.FindControl("txtHeree") as TextBox;
Panel txtVal = e.Row.FindControl("forDiv") as Panel;
```

and, etc..

My current problem is, I still can't find both the equivalent ASP.NET Control for `<i></i>` tags and also for .FindControl() method for it.
sure, I have read the reference to another QnA forum from both Stackoverflow and Microsoft Docs:
[ASP.NET Control to HTML tag equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461901/asp-net-control-to-html-tag-equivalent)
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/server-controls

ANY suggestion, answer, or efficient code for the `<i></i>` tag control, will be very.. very helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: There is no `I` aspnet control. It is just the old Italic html tag. You can do this with css.

Comment: @VDWWD how does it work? can you give me a short example or maybe the alternatives for this kind of case? thx.

Comment: Make a css class that makes text italic and add it to the `CssClass` property of a control.

Comment: if you add a "id" and runat=server tag, then that "<i>" control behaves quite much like any other server side asp.net control. See my example below.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you add a "id" tag, and runat=server, then that "i" thing becomes quite much a server side control.

And doing that allows use in listview, repeaters etc.

So, do this:

```
        <i id="MyIguy" runat="server"></i>
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            CssClass="btn" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

So, with code behind the button like this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyIguy.InnerText = "this is fun";

    }
```

And we see this when run:

[image]

And say we use a gridview, repeater etc.?

say this markup, we just dropped in that  (wiht id, and runat=server).

Quite much makes that control work, look, and feel like any other server side asp.net control.

Say, this markup and gridview (for the find control example).

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel Name"> <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City"> <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description"> <ItemTemplate>
                        <i id="Descript" runat="server"> <%# Eval("Description") %>  </i>
                    </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View"> <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View" 
                        CssClass="btn" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code to load:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And we have this now:

[image]

And our view button click code, say this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        int? PKID = GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"] as int?;

        Debug.Print("pk data base row id = " + PKID.ToString());
        Debug.Print("Row click index = " + gRow.RowIndex);

        // get hotel name
        Label txtHotel = gRow.FindControl("txtHotel") as Label;
        Debug.Print("Hotel name = " + txtHotel.Text);

        // get our <i> guy
        HtmlGenericControl myIthing = gRow.FindControl("Descript") as HtmlGenericControl;
        Debug.Print("Our i guy = " + myIthing.InnerText);

    }
```

Output :

[image]

so, most such controls - adding a "id" and runat="server", and at that point, it quite much behaves like most other asp.net controls.

Comment: at some point, I don't show my complete code on this thread, and yet you give the detailed example using Griedview (and I am using it too). So, thanks.. But, just want to confirm, in the other hand, what if I use <asp:PlaceHolder ID="forITags"  ..... ></asp:PlaceHolder> as the representation of <i></i> tags by controlling it from the .cs file using ...Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<i></i>"}). is that doable also?